# How can I make a carousel with the next and previous image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

Focusing the main image with next and previous image by side in small view.

Comment: Where you stuck in doing that? Your question is not clear! include what you have tried to achieve the same!

Comment: Provide your code here so that it will help us in giving you the solution

Comment: Show your code. Thats what we read here. 
Your description in text is cool but on same token you yourself 
admit that things are going wrong. 
Only source code will reveal the errors. 
If you could update your post with your source code it would be 
highly productive in someone finding the bug. Also please read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved (without jQuery) like so:

```js
const images = [
  "https://images.theconversation.com/files/304244/original/file-20191128-178107-9wucox.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=496&fit=clip",
  "https://bigcats.be/images/resized/750x-header-cat.jpg",
  "https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66820/aImg/34883/bird-article-s.png"
];

const left = document.getElementById("carousel-left");
const middle = document.getElementById("carousel-middle");
const right = document.getElementById("carousel-right");

let currentIndex = 0;

function focusImage() {
  const leftSrc = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length -1 : currentIndex -1;
  const middleSrc = currentIndex;
  const rightSrc = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
  left.src = images[leftSrc];
  middle.src = images[middleSrc];
  right.src = images[rightSrc];
}

function previous() {
  currentIndex = currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex -1;
  focusImage();
}

function next() {
  currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 >= images.length ? 0 : currentIndex +1;
  focusImage();
}

focusImage();

left.addEventListener("click", previous);
right.addEventListener("click", next);
```

```css
#carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.carousel-side {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

#carousel-middle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-container">
  <img id="carousel-left" class="carousel-side">
  <img id="carousel-middle">
  <img id="carousel-right" class="carousel-side">
</div>

<button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I need the onclick event with the next and previous images instead of buttons. How can I do that?

Comment: I have added `EventListeners` to the images using `addEventListener("click", my_function)`

Comment: Lastly, how do I load images from my folder?

Comment: You can reference them like you would reference them directly in the `src` attribute!

Comment: Okay it's working fine with src attribute. If you don't mind, Can you show me how to add animation during onclick event (I mean image changing animation) ?? i'd be so grateful!

Comment: Could you create a new question for that? It is not in scope of this one.

Comment: Okay sure I'm creating a new question with this code for image changing animation. Please answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, you should present the code you already tried for us to help you when you are stuck at something.

As in this case, I understood what you are looking for, I suggest you to use "Slick slider" plugin to achieve this.

Here is the codepen link for you to check the result : [Solution link](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/PoqppvB)

Keep this setting on in JS:

```
centerMode: true
```

Comment: Please avoid link only answers because link rot